# Is there a hybrid enterprise GIS I can setup that will allow me to edit on ArcMap and have geoserver hosted in the cloud

Tags: arcmap, geoserver, postgresql, enterprise

I am looking for a hybrid enterprise GIS that will allow my company to continue using our ArcMap licenses but that doesn’t cost a fortune to do.

It seems like it’s either all open source or it’s all ESRI.

We need to be able to have a multi user/multi editor environment that will allow us to create web apps from.

Is it possible to have ArcMap for editing, GeoServer for serving the data to our editors, and use leaflet or ArcGIS online for web app development?

Answer (score 1):

You have several hidden questions embedded within this broad one but it is possible to edit data in GeoServer from ArcMap (with a Production Mapping license) via WFS-T.

The ArcMap Help has a page on [Data editing with WFS-T services](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/production-mapping/data-editing-with-wfs-services.htm):

> Production Mapping provides a way to consume WFS data, perform edit
> operations, and publish the resulting changes to the service.

Comment: Thanks for responding to my question PolyGeo, I truly appreciate the help! And I will definitely improve my questions asking process. One more question if you would please help me? Do I need to purchase an enterprise license to get the production mapping license?

Comment: @AllisonHockey I don't think so, just Desktop Standard or Advanced - see https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/system-requirements/latest/mapping-and-charting-solutions-system-requirements.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_845407658ACD4E6F8E3CD70922ED9B8C

Answer (score 1):

Although, using a combination of GeoServer, PostGIS and QGIS could respond most of your needs you still have a chance to use ArcGIS.

As a architectural point of view, what you can do is to connect ArcGIS software to database containing spatial data and users are working with them. GeoServer has this ability to connect to that database, too.

Consequently, managers can interact with data such as editing, adding or removing. At the same time, users can retrieve data through GeoServer in form of WMS for example.